# How to install WH_MSGFILTER?

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to catch all messages that receive another program. As I understand I need to use WinApi hooks, specifically WH_MSGFILTER, but I dont know how to install it properly. Can someone show me complete C# program using different WinApi hooks?

Comment: Take a peek at [me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#wh_msgfilter_wh_sysmsgfilterhooks)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooks like that require a DLL that can be injected into another process.  You cannot write such a DLL in C#, you cannot get the CLR injected.  Only the low-level hooks can work, they don't require injection.

Check [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H) for an alternative.  No idea how solid it is btw.

Answer (score 1):

A process hook to another program requires a native dll (except for keyboard and mouse hooks). Can't be done in C#.